# Use CoordinatorLayout with ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Is it possible to use `CoordinatorLayout` with `ListView`?

I have tried the following which does not work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="15dp">

            <ru.boloid.giszkh.views.AppTextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/no_payment_documents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="#EBEFF0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/attention"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nothing_found_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/payment_documents_nothing_found_text_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/payment_documents_nothing_found"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:fillViewport="true">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/pay_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
                android:background="@color/list_background"
                android:divider="@null"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <!--<ListView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/pay_list"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_above="@+id/footer"-->
                <!--android:background="@color/list_background"-->
                <!--android:divider="@null"-->
                <!--/>-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/list_background"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/amount_to_pay_group"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/payment_documents_total_accrued"
                            android:textColor="@color/pay_item_title_text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/payment_documents_footer_text_size"
                            android:textStyle="bold"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/total_accrued"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/pay_item_title_text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/payment_documents_footer_text_size"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            tools:text="995 000.00 P"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/info_amount_in_progress_image"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:scaleX="@dimen/controls_scale_1.4"
                            android:scaleY="@dimen/controls_scale_1.4"
                            android:src="@drawable/info_gray"
                            android:visibility="invisible"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/insurance_group"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/payment_documents_insurance"
                            android:textColor="@color/pay_item_title_text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/payment_documents_footer_text_size"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/insurance_amount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/pay_item_title_text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/payment_documents_footer_text_size"
                            tools:text="132.84 P"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/edit_insurance_image"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:scaleX="@dimen/controls_scale_1.4"
                            android:scaleY="@dimen/controls_scale_1.4"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/paid_amount_group"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/payment_documents_paid"
                            android:textColor="@color/pay_item_title_text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/payment_documents_footer_text_size"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/paid_amount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/pay_item_title_text_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/payment_documents_footer_text_size"
                            tools:text="1 502 000.00 P"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator"/>

                <ru.boloid.giszkh.views.AppButton
                    android:id="@+id/pay_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_card"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:minWidth="130dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/bkgrd_shadow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also one more question: 
How to make my LinearLayout scroll to the top when I reach the bottom of the ListView?

Comment: show your whole xml layout

Comment: No, use RecyclerView

Comment: yup use recyclerview. check this https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: I have already made ListView and I want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

1.add `CustomListView`

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2
            , MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

2.change xml code

**You change this.**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstTask"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="287dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
```

**To**

```
<!-- your package name-->
<com.your.app.utils.CustomListView
    android:id="@+id/lstTask"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Comment: Good luck to you!@ManOfWar

Comment: Do you know, how to make my LinearLayout in the bottom of page scroll up as a ListView element?

Comment: Add it as `ListViiew `'s footer .

Comment: Anyone able to explain what that change to `onMeasure` does? As in, why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a custom ListView subclass. ListView will work directly with CoordinatorLayout as long as you include this attribute:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Then you can use the nested-enabled ListView in exactly the same way you would use a NestedScrollView or RecyclerView.